# How do you define a derive macro crate as a dependency and re-export the procedural macro code

Tags: rust, macros

[In the Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html):

> "The two crates will need to be published separately, and programmers
> using these crates will need to add both as dependencies and bring
> them both into scope. **We could instead have the hello_macro crate use
> hello_macro_derive as a dependency and re-export the procedural macro
> code**. However, the way we’ve structured the project makes it possible
> for programmers to use hello_macro even if they don’t want the derive
> functionality."

Assuming the user will always want the derive functionality, how do you do as suggested and have the hello_macro crate use hello_macro_derive as a dependency and re-export the procedural macro code, with one **use** and one **dependency** instead of two each?

```
[dependencies]
hello_macro = { path = "../hello_macro" }
hello_macro_derive = { path = "../hello_macro/hello_macro_derive" }
```

```
use hello_macro::HelloMacro;
use hello_macro_derive::HelloMacro
#[derive(HelloMacro)]
struct Pancakes;
```

Comment: Is there more to it than just adding `hello_macro_derive` to the `[dependencies]` section of `hello_macro`'s `Cargo.toml`, and adding `pub use hello_macro_derive::whatever` to `lib.rs`? IOW the same way you added the dependency to this crate... just do it in the `hello_macro` crate instead. Or am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: I got it to work by adding to lib.rs in hello_macro

`#[allow(unused_imports)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate hello_macro_derive;
pub use hello_macro_derive::HelloMacro;
`

and adding to hello_macro Cargo.toml

`[dependencies]`
`hello_macro_derive = { path = "./hello_macro_derive" }`

Comment: I am also getting tripped up the RLS which is showing errors which the compiler/cargo check is not showing.

Comment: So @trentcl, yes that is all I needed to do. In VsCode/rust-analyzer it was showing up as an error but `cargo build` built and ran fine. Thanks! No need for the `macro_use` or `extern crate` that I mentioned.